# Не получается вызвать метод в await

Tags: c#, discord

Вообщем метод DailyGetEmbed отвечает за embed message его нужно вызвать в await ReplyAsync(GetMiuniesReport(account.Miunies, target.Mention)); но у меня не получается. библиотека discord.net

```
[Command("balance"), Remarks("Shows how many the mentioned user has")]
        [Alias("Cash", "Money")]
        public async Task CheckMiuniesOther(IGuildUser target)
        {


            var account = _globalUserAccounts.GetById(target.Id);
            await ReplyAsync(DailyGetEmbed(GetMiuniesReport(account.Miunies, target.Mention)));


        }

        public static EmbedBuilder DailyGetEmbed()
        {
            var builder = new EmbedBuilder() 
            {
                Color = new Color(255, 0, 247), 
                Description = "Команды которыми вы можете пользоваться" 
            };

            return builder;

        }
```

Comment: При чем тут `await`? Вы вызываете его с параметром, которого нет в самом метода.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ и как пофиксить?

Comment: Добавить аргументы методу?) Ну или удаляйте их в вызове.